# does the run count

Tags: baseball, scoring

scenario: one out, runners on first and third. Fly to deep centre; fielder makes an exceptional catch for second out, and makes a huge throw to double up the runner from first who had gone too far, thinking the ball would not be caught. Is that a force play at first that negates the fact that the runner from third has crossed the plate before the out at first.

Comment: Sounds like baseball, but to be sure you should always include the sport you're talking about in the tags.

Answer (score 2):

The run scores as this is not a force out. Instead it is a [time play](https://www.umpirebible.com/index.php/rules-base-running/time-plays) - in other words, the third out (at first base in this example) must occur before the runner touches the plate to prevent the score. (The Steve the Ump web site [addresses the situation](http://www.stevetheump.com/scoring_runs.htm) specifically.)

Comment: TBH, I thought the run wouldn't count, but in trying to verify that, I found several web sites that corrected that mistaken belief. You learn something new every day. :-)

Comment: Stack Exchange strongly prefers answers which don't need us to go to another website. Could you summarise in your own words the reasoning directly in your answer please?

Comment: @PhilipKendall: Forgive me, but there's not a lot to explain here (it's basically a yes or no question), and I thought I had explained adequately for someone who is familiar with baseball. I've expanded a bit, hopefully adequately.

Comment: Rules 5.09(b)(5) and 5.09(c)(1) call this an appeal play.

Comment: @chepner: The wording in those rule subsections is confusing, but I don't think this is an appeal play as laid out in the question. An appeal is when the defensive team tags the base after the play is over (but before the next pitch is made).

Comment: 5.09(c)(1) is pretty clear; your idea of an appeal is one *type* of appeal play.

Comment: @chepner: Not that I want to get into some lengthy back & forth, but here's the text of 5.09(c)(1): *"(c) Appeal Plays
Any runner shall be called out, on appeal, when:
(1)  After a fly ball is caught, he fails to retouch his original base before he or his original base is tagged;"* Right from the start, the section states that it applies to making an appeal, but no where in the OP is an appeal mentioned.

Comment: (c)(1) is *explicitly* about the runner being doubled up at 1st. The interesting bit is that the runner has the ability to get back to first before the appeal is made, as opposed to a situation, e.g., where he has already returned to the dugout after scoring on a sacrifice fly.

Comment: @chepner: Yes, *on appeal*; that is the title of the subsection and is then explicitly stated as the first sentence thereof. And you can continue, but I'm done here.